# Jquery Magnific-Popup play local video

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I want to play local video,how can I do that?
I read on the Magnific-Popup documentation that the video just like youtube,not local video.
I change the video_url,but it does not work.
Thx.

Comment: What do you mean by local video?

Comment: Hello,local video is mean D:\www\movie.mp4,not http://www.youtube.com.

Comment: I am not sure if magnific popoup can do that. You need html5 video element to play from local computer.

Comment: OK,I use magnific popup because it is very beautiful,I will use html5 <video> to play local video,thank you for your answer.